Discord.js "ValidationError: Expected a string primitive" when loading commands
I created another command like usual, but it shows the "ValidationError: Expected a string primitive" error and I'm not sure why.
This is the at file:///home/egganto/Documents/Athena/src/commands/perimeter.js:157:33  it's referring to:
import { SlashCommandBuilder } from "discord.js";

const perimeterCommand = new SlashCommandBuilder()
  .setName("perimeter")
  .setDescription("Solves for the perimeter")
  // subcommand for parallelogram
  .addSubcommand((subcommand) =>
    subcommand
    .setName("parallelogram")
    .setDescription("Solves for the perimeter of the parallelogram")
    .addNumberOption((option) =>
      option
      .setName("base")
      .setDescription("The value of the base of the parallelogram")
      .setRequired(true)
    )
    .addNumberOption((option) =>
      option
        .setName("height")
        .setDescription("The value of height of the parallelogram")
        .setRequired(true)
      )
    )

  // subcommand for triangle
  .addSubcommand((subcommand) =>
    subcommand)
    .setName("triangle")
    .setDescription("Finds the perimeter of a triangle")
    .addNumberOption((option) =>
      option
      .setName("a")
      .setDescription("value of side a of the triangle")
      .setRequired(true)
    )
    .addNumberOption((option) =>
      option
      .setName("b")
      .setDescription("value of side b of the triangle")
      .setRequired(true)
    )
    .addNumberOption((option) =>
      option
      .setName("c")
      .setDescription("value of side c of the triangle")
      .setRequired(true)
    )

  // subcommand for rectangle
  .addSubcommand((subcommand) =>
    subcommand
    .setName("rectangle")
    .setDescription("finds the perimeter of a rectangle")
    .addNumberOption((option) =>
      option
      .setName("length")
      .setDescription("value of length of rectangle")
      .setRequired(true)
    )
    .addNumberOption((option) =>
      option
      .setName("width")
      .setDescription("value of length of rectangle")
      .setRequired(true)
    )
  )

  // subcommand for square
  .addSubcommand((subcommand) =>
    subcommand
    .setName("square")
    .setDescription("fnds perimeter of a square")
    .addNumberOption((option) =>
      option
      .setName("a")
      .setDescription("value of a side of a square")
      .setRequired(true)
    )
  )

  // subcommand for trapezoid
  .addSubcommand((subcommand) =>
    subcommand
    .setName("trapezoid")
    .setDescription("finds perimeter of trapezoid")
    .addNumberOption((option) =>
      option
      .setName("a")
      .setDescription("value of side a of trapezoid")
      .setRequired(true)
    )
    .addNumberOption((option) =>
      option
      .setName("b")
      .setDescription("value of side b of trapezoid")
      .setRequired(true)
    )
    .addNumberOption((option) =>
      option
      .setName("c")
      .setDescription("value of side c of trapezoid")
      .setRequired(true)
    )
    .addNumberOption((option) =>
      option
      .setName("d")
      .setDescription("value of side d of trapezoid")
      .setRequired(true)
    )
  )

  // subcommand for kite
  .addSubcommand((subcommand) =>
    subcommand
    .setName("kite")
    .setDescription("finds perimeter of kite")
    .addNumberOption((option) =>
      option
      .setName("a")
      .setDescription("length of first pair of equal sides")
      .setRequired(true)
    )
    .addNumberOption((option) =>
      option
      .setName("b")
      .setDescription("length of second pair of equal sides")
      .setRequired(true)
    )
  )

  // subcommand for rhombus
  .addSubcommand((subcommand) =>
    subcommand
    .setName("rhombus")
    .setDescription("finds perimeter of rhombus")
    .addNumberOption((option) =>
      option
      .setName("a")
      .setDescription("length of a side")
      .setRequired(true)
    )
  )

  // subcommand for hexagon
  .addSubcommand((subcommand) =>
    subcommand
    .setName("hexagon")
    .setDescription("finds perimeter of hexagon")
    .addNumberOption((option) =>
      option
      .setName("a")
      .setDescription("length of a side")
      .setRequired(true)
    )
  );

export default perimeterCommand.toJSON();

line 157:33 being export default perimeterCommand.toJSON();
This is the full error:
[nodemon] starting `node ./src/index.js run`
/home/egganto/Documents/Athena/node_modules/@sapphire/shapeshift/dist/cjs/index.cjs:2473
    return typeof value === "string" ? Result.ok(value) : Result.err(new ValidationError("s.string", "Expected a string primitive", value));
                                                                     ^

ValidationError: Expected a string primitive
    at _StringValidator.handle (/home/egganto/Documents/Athena/node_modules/@sapphire/shapeshift/dist/cjs/index.cjs:2473:70)
    at _StringValidator.parse (/home/egganto/Documents/Athena/node_modules/@sapphire/shapeshift/dist/cjs/index.cjs:939:90)
    at validateName (/home/egganto/Documents/Athena/node_modules/@discordjs/builders/dist/index.js:1578:17)
    at validateRequiredParameters (/home/egganto/Documents/Athena/node_modules/@discordjs/builders/dist/index.js:1597:3)
    at MixedClass.toJSON (/home/egganto/Documents/Athena/node_modules/@discordjs/builders/dist/index.js:2358:5)
    at /home/egganto/Documents/Athena/node_modules/@discordjs/builders/dist/index.js:2506:52
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at MixedClass.toJSON (/home/egganto/Documents/Athena/node_modules/@discordjs/builders/dist/index.js:2506:29)
    at file:///home/egganto/Documents/Athena/src/commands/perimeter.js:157:33
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:222:25) {
  validator: 's.string',
  given: undefined
}

Node.js v20.12.2

I tried checking if I missed any description/require attributes, and if I haven't missed anything, I think it might not be missing something

Line 27 has a trailing closing bracket, and line 47 lacks a closing bracket.
// perimeter.js:25
  // subcommand for triangle
  .addSubcommand((subcommand) =>
    subcommand) // this closes the addSubcommand function
    .setName("triangle")
    .setDescription("Finds the perimeter of a triangle")

